# Using CASE with multiple conditions in Subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, conditional-statements, case

1) Want all records associated with primary key OR_LOG.LOG_ID where OR_LOG.LOC_ID = 4060020

2) Want a column to output "yes" or "no" if the listed Medication_ID was given between the times listed in the script.  Really I want to include 4 medications and have the "yes" or "no" if any of them were given.

3) I was able to get this to sort of work before I added the two time restrictions except it seemed to only show rows that included the medication being given.  I thought the left join was going to take care of that.  When I added the two "and" time statements I got an "invalid character" error.

4) I will have a few more of the same types of subqueries to run using different time frames and different medication_IDs.

5) The database is very large and I am trying be as efficient as I can.

```
SELECT 
   CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOC_ID,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_PREOP_NURSE_NM,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_PROCEDURE_NM,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_PHYSICIAN_NM,
   CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.PRIMARY_RECOVERY_NURSE_NM,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.IN_OR_DTTM,
   CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.OUT_OR_DTTM,
    Case
       When CLARITY.ORDER_MED.MEDICATION_ID = 104661
       and CLARITY.MAR_ADMIN_INFO.TAKEN_TIME  > CLARITY.V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS.PATIENT_IN_PREPROCEDURE_DTTM
       and CLARITY.MAR_ADMIN_INFO.TAKEN_TIME < CLARITY.V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS.PATIENT_OUT_ROOM_DTTM
       then 'YES'
       else 'NO' END AS PONV
FROM CLARITY.OR_LOG
INNER JOIN CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY
ON CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOG_ID = CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.LOG_ID
INNER JOIN CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED
ON CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOG_ID = CLARITY.V_LOG_BASED.LOG_ID
left JOIN CLARITY.MAR_ADMIN_INFO
ON CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.AN_52_ENC_CSN_ID =     CLARITY.MAR_ADMIN_INFO.MAR_ENC_CSN
inner JOIN CLARITY.ORDER_MED
ON CLARITY.MAR_ADMIN_INFO.ORDER_MED_ID = CLARITY.ORDER_MED.ORDER_MED_ID
INNER JOIN CLARITY.V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS
ON CLARITY.F_AN_RECORD_SUMMARY.LOG_ID = CLARITY.V_LOG_TIMING_EVENTS.LOG_ID
WHERE CLARITY.OR_LOG.LOC_ID           = 4060020
```

Comment: I wonder if the different criteria in your when-clause was meant to be or'd instead of and'd? TAKEN_TIME cant be both NULL and at the same time greater or smaller than something. Anyway - you must use "is NULL" instead if "= NULL".

Comment: Thanks Jens... That helped me.  I hadn't made a change to the code that I needed when I added the explicit time constraints.  I changed it as above, but it still doesn't run.

Comment: I think the problem with the left join is that it is followed by an inner join on the left'ed table. This inner join will rule out results where there is no rows for to satisfy the left join. One solution is to make the following joins left as well.